# On page seven vs. on [a/the] page seven

Tags: articles

Do I need to place an article in a phrase like:

```
You could find it on [a/the] page seven.
```

What is the corresponding grammar rule?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No, you do not use an article in phrases of the form "on page X". The corresponding grammar rule is: you do not use an article in phrases of the form "on page X".

Comment: So `on a page seven` is incorrect?

Comment: @Konstantin yes, in general.  There is no doubt some artificial context one could decide in which that sentence would be correct.  Perhaps "the reader sought the numeral 7 on the ninth page of several books, but in the end he found it on a page seven."  Here, the infinite article is used because we arespeeding about one arbitrary page seven out of several possible page sevens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implied *name* of the location is 'page seven'; that carries with it the meaning that the place is a page.  Naming it 'seven' would be too vague as there might also be a chapter called 'seven' and a volume called 'seven'. 
So ***"it's on page seven"*** is fine as the name is all you need. The alternative would be ***"it's on the seventh page,"*** - also fine, because you are then identifying the page by position, not by name.

This pattern is repeated elsewhere.  You wouldn't say ***"take this suitcase to the room seven,"*** just as you wouldn't say ***"the suitcase belongs to the Konstantin."***  However, you might say ***"take this suitcase to the front bedroom."***  In that case, 'the front bedroom' is not a name, only an identifying description (with preceding adjective).

Comment: JHCP, thank you for the reply! How is it possible to distinguish in general that "front bedroom" isn't a name, but "room seven" is?

Comment: Common usage suggests that if the identifier ('seven') is preceded by the type ('page'), then it's being used as a name.  Note that this doesn't apply to existing (proper) names, where a preceding *type* would not become part of the name and so would need the article: *"on board the starship Enterprise"*, *"we were visited by the angel Gabriel"*,  except where the type is actually a *title* and therefore part of the name (*"we were visited by General Eisenhower"*).